# xpath-How to replace a window action in Odoo

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-10

I need to replace a button function which is a window action in sale.order form view, for making the button visible to a certain group of users.How to achieve that.

This is the button function to be replaced:

```
<button name="%(action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"        
    type="action" class="btn-primary"                       
    attrs="{'invisible': [('invoice_status', '!=', 'to invoice')]}"/> 

<button name="%(action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"                            
    type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}"                            
    attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"/>
```

Comment: That really is a tricky one.

Comment: yes it is. I tried <xpath expr="//form/sheet/header/button[@name='456']" position="replace"/> but didnt work

Comment: Never use fixed values like the action id. The great challenge is, that the only usable attributes to distinguish both buttons are the pythonic ones, except for the first button, where `class` can be used. But you have to look for others extensions, if you use more than the `sale` module.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not seem to understand what you trying to do, so you have a button that has an action and you want to change what? That action? Or the visibility of the button?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> I think you need to inherit the action in the button
> ```

```
<record id="action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Invoice Order</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">sale.advance.payment.inv</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_sale_salesman'))]"/>
        </record>
```

> Inherited action :

**buy calling action with module name**

```
<record id="sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Invoice Order</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">sale.advance.payment.inv</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_sale_salesman'))]"/>
        </record>
```

> Then you can give certain group in group_id